# Haproxy reload with different backend server ip

Tags: docker, load-balancing, haproxy

Is it possible to reload haproxy while the backend server ip changed? If, how?

It is essential for docker stack. On every deploy, new containers with different ip will replace the old containers.

In our implementation, services return 503 occasionally as the old haproxy process is not terminated and still accepting request, while the backend server is already gone. httplog show that some requests forward a backend which is gone.

```
# ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root       893  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Zs   19:39   0:01 [haproxy] <defunct>
root       898  0.3  0.0  49416  9640 ?        Ss   19:49   0:13 /usr/local/sbin/haproxy -D -f /app/haproxy.cfg -p /var/run/haproxy.pid 
root       915  0.2  0.0      0     0 ?        Zs   19:49   0:12 [haproxy] <defunct>
root       920  0.2  0.0  49308 10196 ?        Ss   20:57   0:01 /usr/local/sbin/haproxy -D -f /app/haproxy.cfg -p /var/run/haproxy.pid 
root       937  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Zs   20:57   0:00 [haproxy] <defunct>
root       942  0.3  0.0  49296  9880 ?        Ss   20:58   0:01 /usr/local/sbin/haproxy -D -f /app/haproxy.cfg -p /var/run/haproxy.pid 
root       959  0.2  0.0  49296  9852 ?        Ss   20:58   0:01 /usr/local/sbin/haproxy -D -f /app/haproxy.cfg -p /var/run/haproxy.pid
```

[Edit]
I am using docker swarm mode. I did try with publish service's port to the host; however, the performance of the swarm’s internal load balancer is bad, and I try to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

While it should be possible to change the HAProxy configuration to point to a different backend server, it seems like it would be easier [to bind the Docker containers' ports to predictable ports on the Docker host](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose), so the HAProxy config does not need to change.

For example:

```
docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:80:9999 hello_world
```

And your HAProxy config could look like

```
backend something
    # Assuming the Docker host's IP address is 192.0.2.123
    server some-server 192.0.2.123:9999
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For docker stack, I am using docker swarm mode. Port forwarding isn't really an option. I did try publishing port to the host; however, the performance of the swarm’s internal load balancer is very bad. Is static ip the solution of this?

Comment: @benjah1 I do not have much experience with docker swarm, but [this page seems to describe exactly your situation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/ingress/#configure-an-external-load-balancer)? It looks you should not publish a container's ports in swarm mode; instead [you would publish a service's ports](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/ingress/#publish-a-port-for-a-service).